# How to use Fluid cObject data in Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, view-helpers

I have following fluid script to insert a typoscript lib:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.artteaser" data="{imgclass: 'img-cover'}"/>
```

I want to use the "data" parameter in a typoscript within `FILES.renderObj` for the  wrap as a css class - the following is what I've tried so far, but it didnt work.

```
lib.artteaser = COA
lib.artteaser {

    wrap = <section><div class="container"><div class="row cover-teaserbox">|</div></div></section>

    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            [...]
        }

        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {

            wrap = <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 cover-teaserbox-item">|</div>

            10 = FILES
            10 {

                references {
                    [...]
                }

                renderObj = IMAGE
                renderObj {
                    file.import.data = file:current:uid
                    file.crop.data = file:current:crop
                    file.treatIdAsReference = 1
                    altText.data = file:current:title

                    # the following did not work
                    stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="cover-teaserbox-item-img {field:imgclass}">|</div>

                    stdWrap.typolink {
                        parameter.field =  pid
                    }
                }

                maxItems = 1

            }

            [...]

        }

    }

}
```

Can somebody give me a hint to get this to work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure, But try `10.current = 1` in the FILE object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you use `current` or `field:*` or `data = *` you need to consider context.

On entering your TS object you have all your 'parameters' as current context. but as soon as you build a menu or work on records (`CONTENT`) the single record (page record in case of menus) is the current context.

In your case you can store your parameter to a register and use it later.

```
lib.artteaser = COA
lib.artteaser {

    5 = LOAD_REGISTER
    5 {
        imageClass.field = imgclass
    }

    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
           :
           :
               stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="cover-teaserbox-item-img {register:imageClass}">|</div>
           :
           :
    }
}
```